# Set Page Title on asp content where it uses master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, html

Ok this an odd way of doing this, I know I should have done it on Page_Load in every pages when using Masterpage, but is there a way around this issue? I don't want to rebuild the pages if I can help it,if I can only insert a title on `<asp:content></asp:content>` it would be easier.

If anyone has run into this or maybe have a suggestion of a good way to do it , I know jquery can do it document.title ='' but I heard it's not SEO friendly.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing can be done through the Content control; only from code-behind.

Answer (score 16):

You can still set the title in each page that's using a MasterPage. In markup: -

```
<%@ Page Title="Your Title" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_masterpages/... etc
```

Or in code: -

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Your Title";
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I'm tryin to avoid coz I have to rebuild the pages. thanks tho

Answer (score 9):

you can place a contentplaceholer in your master page as..

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

After that In content page add its reference as..

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<title>  Your title goes here.  </title>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: omg! I'm excited this , I didn't know you could do this. I'll give you plus 20 if this works!

Answer (score 8):

more simple solution in Master page

<%: Page.Title %> - the main title goes here

in content page first line of it
<%@ Page Title="Your Title" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_masterpages/... etc

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question but what definitely works for me is to set a Literal control in the title tag of the MasterPage like this:

```
<title><asp:Literal runat="server" id="pagetitle" Text="MyTitle"></asp:Literal></title>
```

Then, in the content page, put this in the Page_Load method:

```
Literal myTitleLiteral = (Literal)Master.FindControl("pagetitle");
    if (myTitleLiteral != null)
    {
        myTitleLiteral.Text = "Test Title"; 
    }
```